# Why does 'tr' with '-c' option and set 2 extension add an unwarranted character to the end?

Tags: text-processing, tr

I wanted to use `tr` to substitute "illegal" characters in a string with a replacement character, where "illegal" characters are all outside of a set of "allowed" characters (*i.e.* they are the complement of the set of allowed characters). However, when using the `-c` option and either the explicit `*` repeat specifier or the implicit extension of "set 2", `tr` appends an *additional* instance of the replacement character to the output.

**To reproduce**

- Let the "allowed" characters be `a-n`, specified literally as `abcdefghijklmn`.
- Let the replacement character be `z`.
- Let the input string be either `hell` or `hello`. The expected output string is then `hell` and `hellz`, respectively.

**Demonstration**

1. Illegal characters present, implicit set 2 extension

   ```shellsession
   $ echo "hello" | tr -c 'abcdefghijklmn' 'z'
   hellzz
   ```

   The expected output is `hellz`.
2. Only allowed characters present, implicit set 2 extension

   ```shellsession
   $ echo "hell" | tr -c 'abcdefghijklmn' 'z'
   hellz
   ```

   The expected output is `hell`.
3. Illegal characters present, explicit set 2 extension

   ```shellsession
   $ echo "hello" | tr -c 'abcdefghijklmn' '[z*]'
   hellzz
   ```

   The expected output is `hellz`.
4. Only allowed characters present, explicit set 2 extension

   ```shellsession
   $ echo "hell" | tr -c 'abcdefghijklmn' '[z*]'
   hellz
   ```

   The expected output is `hell`.
5. The same happens when I use a here-string instead of echo-pipe (actually, the here-string was the construct I used when I stumbled upon this effect for the first time):

   ```shellsession
   $ tr -c 'abcdefghijkl' '[z*]' <<< "hello"
   hellzz
   ```

Why does `tr` append an additional `z` here?

This is on Linux, with bash, UTF-8 locale, and `tr` from both GNU coreutils 8.25 and 8.30.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's because `echo` adds a newline to the end of what you tell it to print. The same is true if you use a here-string instead.

So `echo "hello"` actually prints `hello\n`:

```bash
$ echo hello | od -c
0000000   h   e   l   l   o  \n
0000006
```

And that's why you see this:

```bash
$ echo "hell" | tr -c 'abcdefghijklmn' 'z'
hellz$
```

Note how there is no trailing newline there, and the `$` of my prompt appears right after the last `z`. That's because the `\n` printed at the end of `hello\n` is replaced by a `z`. If you use `printf` instead, it works as expected:

```bash
$ printf "hello" | tr -c 'abcdefghijklmn' 'z'
hellz$
```

(`printf %s "$string"` for arbitrary strings, not <strike>`printf "$string"`</strike>)

Or, if you use an `echo` that supports it, use `echo -n`:

```bash
$ echo -n "hello" | tr -c 'abcdefghijklmn' 'z'
hellz$
```

Or if you have a standard UNIX `echo` (like the `echo` builtin of `bash` when both the `posix` and `xpg_echo` options are enabled) use `\c` which causes `echo` to stop outputting:

```bash
$ echo 'hello\c' | tr -c 'abcdefghijklmn' 'z'
hellz$
```

---

But most likely you want to preserve that line delimiter in the input instead so the output still be proper text:

```bash
printf '%s\n' "$string" | tr -c 'abcdefghijklmn\n' '[z*]'
```

(here using the standard POSIX syntax and `printf` instead of `echo` which makes it more obvious that a newline is added and also avoids problems with strings that start with `-` or contain `\` characters).

Also note that, depending on the `tr` implementation, it may leave the bytes that can't be decoded into characters alone (not changed to `z`), while in some others like GNU `tr`, that only works correctly for text (and in locales) with a single byte per character.

Another approach is to use `sed` which at least with the GNU implementation works better in that regard:

```bash
sed 's/[^abcdefghijklmnz]/z/g'
```

`sed` works on the *contents* of the line, so the newline characters are preserved automatically.

Comment: @AdminBee FYI a here string has to append a newline because its purpose is to turn a string into something that text-processing tools can treat the same way as they'd treat an input file and a valid text file per POSIX always has a terminating newline. So for the string `hello` to become a valid input file for tools like awk, sed, grep, read, etc. `<<<'hello'` has to output `hello\n`.

Comment: @EdMorton huh, if you explain it that way, it actually sounds rather obvious :)

Comment: @EdMorton, I'm not sure which of `zsh` or Byron Rakitzis's clone of `rc` introduced `<<<` first (both had it in mid-1991; 1.0 for rc, 2.0 for zsh; [rc's 0.9 announcement doesn't mention it](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.lang.misc/f74XmNS9WWM/_3TZrSkD1IIJ)), but in `rc` (and derivatives like `es` or `akanga`) `<<<` does *not* add a newline.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks for the info, I've never heard of `rc` before. The man page for it I found at https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/rc.1.html shows the example of `cat <<< 'this is a here string' | wc` but doesn't mention what the expected output would be - given what you say I assume it'd be 0 for the number of newlines but without your clue I'd have expected 1 like with bash.